# Parse change Username with Facebook Login Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, parse-platform

I want to update the Username in my parse backend with the username I am receiving from the Facebook Graph API (me Request). Receiving the name is working.
After executing the loginwithreadPermissions-Method I have an valid accesstoken but I am not able to update the username in parse.

```
public void Login(View view) {
    Log.d("Facebook_login", "Login Executed");
       ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(Facebook_login.this, Arrays.asList("user_status", "read_stream", "user_about_me", "email", "public_profile"), new LogInCallback() {
           @Override
           public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if(err!=null){
                Log.d("Facebook_login", err.getMessage());
            }
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d("Facebook_login", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                Toast.makeText(Facebook_login.this,"User is still null, Login not Worked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        accessToken,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                String username;
                                try{
                                    username= object.getString("name");

                                    Log.d("GraphRequestME", username);
                                    user.put("name",username);
                                    user.saveInBackground();
                                    user.getUsername();
                                    Log.d("GraphRequest",user.get("name").toString());
                                }
                                catch (Exception e){
                                    Log.e("Execption", e.getMessage());
                                }
                                Log.d("GraphRequestME", object.toString());
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
                Log.d("Facebook_login", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
            if(user!=null){
                if(accessToken!=null){
                    Log.d("AccessToken", accessToken.getToken());
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Facebook_login.this, MainActivity.class);
                Facebook_login.this.startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("Facebook_login", "LoggedInSuccessful");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the Quickstart Guide(https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-signing-up) from Parse it is described with user.put and later user.saveInBackground() but this isn't working here.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I just found out that the UpdatedAt column (in Parse) is updating to the date I made the last request. But not the colums I want to update

Answer (score 0):

The `username` field has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0. Once all apps have been migrated, you'll not be able to get the `username` anymore from the Graph API.

Comment: I am not getting the username from the GraphAPI, all the data from the GraphAPI is exactly what I wanted, but I am not able to store(update) the relevant data in my parse user

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I figured out that I have to delete the user first and then execute this again and the new attributes got set.
Seems to me that I couldn't edit an existing user with user.put(...)